# Destructor for a doubly-linked list that points to its value

Tags: c++, memory, linked-list

Suppose I have a doubly-linked list defined by the class

```
    class list
    {
        /*...*/

    private:
        struct node
        {
           node* prev;
           node* next;
           int* value;
        }

        node* first; //NULL if none
        node* last; //NULL if none

        /*...*/
    }
```

If I wanted to make a destructor for this list do I have to explicitly delete the value?

```
list::~list()
{
    node* move = first;
    while(first)
    {
        first = move->next;
        delete move;
        move = first;
    }
}
```

Would the above work to ensure that no memory is leaked?  Or do I have to do:

```
list::~list()
{
    node* move = first;
    while(first)
    {
        first = move->next;
        delete move->value;
        delete move->prev;
        delete move;
        move = first;
    }
}
```

I'm confused as to how I can make sure that no memory is leaked in this case.  How do I deal with the pointers in the nodes specifically?  If I delete move does it automatically take care of these?

Comment: Having a node that _points_ to the value is prone to errors and undefined behaviors... What if you add a node pointing to a local variable in a function? After the function returns that pointer is no longer valid.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pair each `new` with exactly one `delete`. That is, you probably don't want to `delete prev` (this node already was deleted) but you want to `delete value`. Well, I'd embed the `value` into the object and *not* point to it:

```
struct node
{
     node* prev;
     node* next;
     int   value;
};
```

If the `value` absolutely needs to be a pointer, I'd use a `std::unique_ptr<int>` (or, if you need to use C++ 2003, a `std::auto_ptr<int>`).

Comment: You should delete value only if you do new, if the user of the class does the allocation, the user should do the deletion

Answer (score 1):

For each successful `new` expression, call `delete` exactly *once* on that object.

For each successful `new[]` expression, call `delete[]` exactly *once* on that object.

That means that neither of your cleanup functions are OK:

- The first function forgets to `delete` the `value`, which means a **memory leak**.
- The second function, by deleting both `move` and `move->prev` at each node in the list, risks deleting most nodes twice, which is **Undefined Behavior**.

To avoid the memory leak for the first function, simply store the integer directly instead of allocating it dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you have to delete the memory pointer by the `value` member - only you can know. It is a question of memory ownership, a question of your design. If the list *owns* the data memory pointed by the `value` members, then you have to delete it in the list destructor (i.e. when the list dies, the data it owned dies with it).

If the list does not own the `value` memory, then you are not supposed to delete it. Again, only you can answer the question of whether your list is supposed to own the `value` memory. It is a matter of your intent.

Now, as for the memory occupied by `node` objects, it is obviously owned by the list, so it has to be carefully deallocated in the destructor. The first version of your destcructor is close to being correct (the second makes no sense at all), except that it written in a slightly obfuscated fashion. This should be sufficient

```
list::~list()
{
  while (first)
  {
    node *move = first;
    first = first->next;
    delete move;
  }
}
```

(Again, if you have to delete `value`, then `delete move->value` should be added to your cycle before `delete move`.)

P.S. Once you get this, you might want to look into various smart pointer classes, which allow you to explicitly express memory ownership relationsips, thus making them known to the compiler. When used properly, they will make memory management almost automatic.